# Laravel lang error with no explanation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

I'm having troubles with a lang file in my project. Turns out that I created lang files for the different views, but one in particular is getting an error and it's not displaying any explanation of the error.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ulzQ.png):

> 1 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
>       .../app/lang/en/opportunities.php:6
>
> 0 Illuminate\Exception\Handler handleShutdown <#unknown>:0
>
> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

[Lang PHP File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnwZr.png):

```
return array(

    'opportunities_' => 'Opportunities',
    'products-and-services' => 'Products and Services',
    'applied-opportunities' => 'Applied Opportunities',
    'control-panel' => 'Control Panel',
    'filters' => 'Filters',
    'oppportunity' => 'Opportunity type',  // <-- key has 3 p's in OP's screenshot
    'select' => 'Select',
    'radio' => 'Radio',
    'festival' => 'Festival',
    'venue' => 'Venue',
    'country' => 'Country',
    'select-country' => 'Select country',
    'city' => 'City',
    'select-city' => 'Select a city',
    'music-genre' => 'Music Genre',
    'date' => 'Date',
    'filter' => 'Filter',
    'application-sent-message' => 'Your application has been sent! If you want to see it, go to your list of applications.',
    'uncompleted-profile-message' => 'Remember to complete your band profile. It will be important in the reviewing process.',
    'see-profile' => 'See Profile',
    'about-the-oppotunity' => 'About the Opportunity',  // <-- key missing r in OP's screenshot
    'download-the-bases' => 'Download the bases',
    'deadline' => 'Deadline',
    'apply' => 'Apply',
    'more-information' => 'More Information',
    'download-file' => 'Download File',
    'gallery' => 'Gallery',
    'get-coupon-code' => 'Get coupon code',
    'exchange-code' => 'Exchange Code',

};  // <!-- erroneous curly bracket to close the array in OP's screenshot
```

Comment: I've inserted your linked images, but code should be displayed as text.

Comment: Can you provide the log of this error? How do you call Lang in blade files?

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, my array closing had the mistake :)

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa ! I'll do it next time ;)

Comment: Flagged as off-topic -> typo.  This question will have no value to future SO readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing the array with `}` on the last line, should be `)`. ;)